# i cant understand the flow of "for" loop in the following program for prime number.please explain

Tags: c#

The following is the code to find prime numbers using "for" loop.

```
using System;
class ChkNum
{
    // Return true if x is prime.
    public bool IsPrime(int x)
    {
        if (x <= 1) return false;
        for (int i = 2; i <= x / i; i++)//didn't understand the condition (i<=x/i) 
            if ((x % i) == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
class ParmDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ChkNum ob = new ChkNum();
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
            if (ob.IsPrime(i)) Console.WriteLine(i + " is prime.");
            else Console.WriteLine(i + " is not prime.");
    }
}
```

Above code is to find prime number.please explain the flow of for loop.

the output of above code is

2 is prime.
3 is prime.
4 is not prime.
5 is prime.
6 is not prime.
7 is prime.
8 is not prime.
9 is not prime

i put values in the code and did the debugging.but i am having problem only over there first 'for' loop i.e i have commented a sentence there.

can you please explain me it by debugging?

Comment: Have you tried to print it out what's it doing?

Comment: Grab a pen and a piece of paper and run through the code by hand. Write down the value of each variable and each condition evaluation.

Comment: I recommend *debugging*. Execute the program step by step and watch the variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could understand your confusion.

The procedure is implementing the [Trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division) method for testing primality.

> This routine consists of dividing *n* by each integer *m* that is greater than 1 and less than or equal to the square root of *n*.

The condition `i <= x / i` is just a strange way to check for `i <= Math.Sqrt(x)` as mentioned above.

It would be much clearer (and overall better) to write it this way

```
for (int i = 2, max = (int)Math.Sqrt(x); i <= max; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: if I keep values then for(i=2;i<10;i++) { if ob.IsPrime(2)).....}                                 Then in IsPrime method                                                                              for(i=2;i<=2/2;i++){........}                                                                                      are values kept correct if not please correct it and tell me how?

Comment: @vishalk Sure I will, but I don't get the question, could you please rephrase it,

Comment: means i just put values in code and tried to debug.could you also do the same for me and elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip all divisors `i > x / i` because when you divide x on such i result of division will be <= i and you already checked that divisor earlier in your cycle.

Comment: Also note that mathematically, since it is given that `i` is positive, the condition `i <= x / i` is equivalent to `i * i <= x` or in other words `i` must be less than or equal to the (real and positive) square root of `x`.